# How to construct client context in AEM by passing values from an external system?

Tags: aem

Is there a way to construct the client context in AEM by using values passed by an external website? The external website sends the user information such as IP address, page data, geolocation, etc. I want to construct the ClientContext JSON without using CQ_Analytics.ClientContextMgr.init, as the information is from an external system.

For eg: We know the location of a visitor to our website. We want to pass this value to AEM and set the client context so that we can get the targeted content for this location.

Our end goal is to get something like this (but we are trying to achieve this without constructing the JSON by ourselves):

CQ_Analytics.ClientContextMgr.clientcontext = JSON.parse('{"profile":{"country":"US"}}');

Is there any Javascript APIs provided by AEM to construct the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the client context using AEM documentation provided at: 
[Creating a Custom Context Store Component](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/personalization/client-context.html#Example:%20Creating%20a%20Custom%20Context%20Store%20Component)

Follow the instructions till the [Initialization](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/personalization/client-context.html#Create%20the%20Initialization%20Script) part where you will need to populate the data in the jsp file for your extension.

So in your case it would be something this:

```
if(!locstore){
    locstore = CQ_Analytics.JSONPStore.registerNewInstance("<%= store %>", 
    "<%= jsonpurl %>",{});
}
```

Where `jsonpurl` will be the location of your service that provides the external data in json(p) format. This will initialise your store with the values you want and you won't need to worry about the manual json handcrafting.

> Client context is constructed on client side using the JS library in AEM. You will need some binding parameters to connect your external data source to the current client context.

The detailed tutorial can be found [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/personalization/client-context.html).